# How can I recognize a valid barcode using regex?

Tags: regex

I have a barcode of the format `123456########`. That is, the first 6 digits are always the same followed by 8 digits. 
How would I check that a variable matches that format?

Comment: You might want to specify what programming language you intend to implement this in. Regular expressions are relatively standardized, but some specific languages have quirks/limitations that you should be aware of and which might impact the accuracy of answers given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't specified a language, but regexp. syntax is relatively uniform across implementations, so something like the following should work: `123456\d{8}`

- `\d` Indicates numeric characters and is typically equivalent to the set `[0-9]`.
- `{8}` indicates repetition of the preceding character set precisely eight times.

Depending on how the input is coming in, you may want to anchor the regexp. thusly:

```
^123456\d{8}$
```

Where `^` matches the beginning of the line or string and `$` matches the end. Alternatively, you may wish to use word boundaries, to ensure that your bar-code strings are properly separated:

```
\b123456\d{8}\b
```

Where `\b` matches the empty string but only at the edges of a word (normally defined as a sequence consisting exclusively of alphanumeric characters plus the underscore, but this can be locale-dependent).

Answer (score 5):

`123456\d{8}`

```
123456  # Literals
\d      # Match a digit
  {8}   # 8 times
```

You can change the `{8}` to any number of digits depending on how many are after your static ones.

[Regexr will let you try out the regex.](http://regexr.com?31c7e)

Answer (score 3):

```
123456\d{8}
```

should do it. This breaks down to:

- 123456 - the fixed bit, obviously substitute this for what you're fixed bit is, remember to escape and regex special characters in here, although with just numbers you should be fine
- \d     - a digit
- {8}    - the number of times the previous element must be repeated, 8 in this case.

the `{8}` can take 2 digits if you have a minimum or maximum number in the range so you could do `{6,8}` if the previous element had to be repeated between 6 and 8 times.

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe it, it's just

```
^123456[0-9]{8}$
```

...where you'd replace `123456` with your 6 known digits. I'm using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` because I don't know what flavor of regex you're using, and `\d` allows non-Arabic numerals in some flavors (if that concerns you).